# Rails send an automatic reminder email 3 days after field update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, cron

I have an app with an association between User and Project.  When a user signs up they are sent a quick survey.  If the survey indicates they would be a good match for our website they are granted access and sent an email asking them to fill out their profile and their project info.  This is the controller that handles that action.

```
class Admin::Users::GrantAccessesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attribute(:access_granted, true)
      if params[:email] == "true"
        @user.send_access_granted_email
      end
      redirect_to admin_users_path
    else
     redirect_to admin_users_path
    end
  end
```

I want to set up a command that would automatically email someone a reminder 3 days after they are granted access if they haven't filled out their project yet.  I only want to email them one reminder.

I have a few ideas and I'm hoping everyone could give me advice one the best option.

1. Use whenever gem to set up a cron job (problematic because I only want to send one email not endless emails until they update their project.  I'm also not sure how to add if statements to a cron job)

   ```
   every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
     runner "Task.send_email" (if access granted and project not updated/created)
   end
   ```
2. use UserMailer to send email (I'm not sure how to trigger the email to be sent 3 days after access granted if no project)

   ```
      # Sends project_reminder e-mail
      def send_project_reminder_email
       UserMailer.project_reminder(self).deliver_now
      end
   ```
3. Put something like the following on the user model to do something if granted_access is updated.

   ```
   def update
    @model = Model.find(params[:id])
    detect_changes

    if @model.update_attributes(params[:model])
     send email if attr_changed?
    end
   end  

   private

   def detect_changes
     @changed = []
     @changed << :attr if @model.attr != params[:model][:attr]
   end

   def attr_changed?
     @changed.include :attr
   end
   ```

   None of these solutions seem to really solve the whole problem.  I think the steps are

1) After access is granted flag a user to check back in 3 days.

2) 3 days later check if project has been updated.

3) if updated do nothing, if not updated send email.

I've never done anything like this so I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around a solution.  Many thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 3):

I've had success using `whenever` like this:

In config/schedule.rb (arrange for your task to run):

```
every 1.day, :at => "9am" do
  rake "notifications:send"
end
```

In lib/tasks/notifications.rake (your actual task that calls your method in UserMailer for each email that needs to be sent):

```
namespace :notifications do
  desc "Sends daily notifications to admins and users"
  task :send => :environment do
    User.all.each do |user|
      # This is where to decide whether to send to any given individual user
      UserMailer.daily_stakeholder_events_to_user(user).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

In app/mailers/user_mailer.rb (now sending out one email):

```
  def daily_stakeholder_events_to_user(user)
    user.email = "email@example.com"
    subject = "Daily Email Alert"
    @user = user
    @events = []

    email_with_name = "#{@user.full_name} <#{@user.email}>"
    puts "Emailing #{subject} to #{email_with_name}"
    mail(:to => email_with_name, :subject => subject)
  end
```

And, finally, in app/views/user_mailer/daily_stakeholder_events_to_user.html.erb (your HTML for the body of the email):

```
<p>Hello <%= @user.full_name %>!</p>
<p>You have <%= @events.count %> <%= "event".pluralize(@events.count) %>.<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Time/day` method from Ruby's library, add a date to when the email was sent, log it, and have the method send an email if it's been 72 hours

```
require 'date'

def three_days_later
    File.open('email_log.txt', 'r').each_line do |check|
      # find the email address
      if check.include?(04/17/16) 
        #If the email includes the same day, don't send
        puts "Hasn't been 72 hours.."
      else 
        #resend email
    end
  end
end
```

Then from your email method:

```
class Admin::Users::GrantAccessesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attribute(:access_granted, true)
      if params[:email] == "true"
        @user.send_access_granted_email
      end
      redirect_to admin_users_path
      #log the data for the time information
    else
     redirect_to admin_users_path
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

`whenever` is a good gem. But it requires `unix` platform. Beside this, whenever doesn't work with `heroku`.
Another good alternative is [Clockwork Gem](https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork)

```
require 'clockwork'

module Clockwork
  every(10.seconds, 'frequent.job')
end
```

You can even schedule your background job using this gem.

Comment: I can't edit the answer, but here is the new link to Clockwork Github page: https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork